# XML UTF-8 encoding lost after Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, utf-8, applescript

I have an applescript code where part of it requires interrogation of XML to get data. I am using Xpath for this. The XML is not in a file, it is set to a variable in applescript (it was obtained from a web query earlier in the code).

This XML is UTF-8 encoded and contains some special characters, such as ø. This appears fine in applescript however once the XML is passed through xpath it looses the UTF-8 encoding and my special characters appear incorrect.

The applescript I am using for the Xpath is:

```
    set theXpath to "(//LastName)"
    set myXPathResult to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of XMLfinal & "| xpath " & quoted form of theXpath
```

An example of the bit of XML I am interested in is:

```
    <LastName>Bergsjø</LastName>
```

but gets spit back by Xpath as:

```
    <LastName>Bergsj¯</LastName>
```

I have looked everywhere for why this is happening but I can't find anything that even remotely makes sense or is applicable.

I've also looked into going around the problem by converting the text to ASCII encoding with iconv but that doesn't seem to work either (says cannot convert).

I also started trying to use applescript's text delims in order to get the info I want, but this will result in a lot of extra work, basically rewriting my whole code as I query lots of different parts of the XML. This seems messy and illogical as I appear to be just one small step away from ti working correctly.

I am new to coding so I apologise if I haven't included all the necessary information. I would really appreciate some help as this has me climbing the walls!

Comment: You should not need the **echo** command, so re-write your code like this, and see what happens: `set myXPathResult to (do shell script (quoted form of XMLfinal) & " | xpath " & quoted form of theXpath) as text`

Comment: Unfortunately it then seems to think I'm giving it a file name as it comes back with the error:
File name too long

        no element found at line 1, column 0, byte 0:

        ^
         at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-         2level/XML/Parser.pm line 187.

Comment: 'code' Ok @Craig Smith, so I definitely thing it is something to do with xpath and not the Echo issue as when I put the XMl in a file and in terminal do: `cat newXML.xml` the file reads out with characters appearing correctly. However, if I then try `cat newXML.xml | xpath '//LastName'` I retrieve the data but the character encoding is gone and ø reads like ?

Comment: OK, rats.  Seems unbelievable that anything in the modern environment would not be unicode compliant.  I will see if I can mess with it over the weekend and come up with some ideas.

Comment: AppleScript encodes some things in MacRoman for backwards compatibility. I got bitten by the encoding bug today and found out the hard way that `read` and `write` need `as «class utf8»` or Unicode characters will get munged. The [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW34) mentions this problem in the write command, but not in the part about strings.